# Conditionally change node background color inside foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I generate 8 rectangle nodes using a `\foreach` loop but I would like one of them (the one at the `position` index) to have a gray background.

How can I do that ? I would like to *avoid repeating* the `\node[simd element]` command in the if and else branches of the conditional jump.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Definitions
\setlength{\elemwidth}{4ex};
\setlength{\dotswidth}{4ex};
\setlength{\labelsepa}{0.2cm};
\tikzset{simd element/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    inner xsep=0.1ex,
    font=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    minimum width=\elemwidth,
    minimum height=\heightof{A[0]}+0.666em
}};
%%%% Define variable position := 3
% Source 1
\node[label] (src1lbl) {$I_{ndex}$};
\foreach \val [count=\i] in {04, 03, 06, 0f, 0a, 08, 02, 0c} {
    \node[simd element] (src1\i) [right=\labelsepa of src1lbl.east,  
        xshift=(\i-1)*\elemwidth, outer sep=0] {\val};
    %%%% if \i == position
    %%%% set background color to gray
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Render]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have different ways of comparing things and in the end send it to a variable. So below is only one way of many other ways such as storing the choices into keys and selecting them accordingly etc. This one is simple in particular because it assumes that there is no previous fill in the boxes so sets them to none.

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % In the preamble

....

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Definitions - Don't spend register on such simple stuff
\def\elemwidth{4ex};
\def\dotswidth{4ex};
\def\labelsepa{0.2cm};
\tikzset{simd element/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    inner xsep=0.1ex,
    font=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    minimum width=\elemwidth,
    minimum height=\heightof{A[0]}+0.666em
}};
%%%% Define variable position := 3
\def\mypos{3}
% Source 1
\node[label] (src1lbl) {$I_{ndex}$};
\foreach \val [count=\i] in {04, 03, 06, 0f, 0a, 08, 02, 0c} {
\ifnum\i=\mypos\relax\def\mytestcolor{gray}\else\def\mytestcolor{none}\fi
    \node[simd element,fill=\mytestcolor] (src1\i) [right=\labelsepa of src1lbl.east,  
        xshift=(\i-1)*\elemwidth, outer sep=0] {\val};
    %%%% if \i == position
    %%%% set background color to gray
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]